# how to avoid printing lines while matching regex in awk

Tags: regex, awk

I am finding the number of certain patterns in a file using below awk command:

```
awk -F" " '
    seconds[$3]=1;
    /\[[a-z_]*\] start/{start[$3]++}
    /\[[a-z_]*\] end/{end[$3]++;sumresptime[$3]+=substr($(NF-1),2)}

END {
    num = asorti(seconds, indices);
    for (i=1;i<=num;i++)
    {
            requests = start[indices[i]] > 0 ? start[indices[i]] : 0;
            responses = end[indices[i]] > 0 ? end[indices[i]] : 0;
            avgresptime = end[indices[i]] > 0 ? sumresptime[indices[i]]/end[indices[i]] : 0;

            print indices[i]" "requests"|"responses"|"avgresptime"
    }
}' $logfile
```

The problem is that it is printing all the lines which are matched by the regex using for calculation. How can I avoid printing lines on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enclose the first expression `seconds[$3]=1;` into square brackets `{}` to prevent "*direct*" evaluation:

```
'{ seconds[$3]=1 }'
```

---

Besides, if all fields in your input file separated by "arbitrary" whitespaces, no need to specify `-F" "` - ***awk*** will separate by whitespace(s) automatically (by default)